# Как корректно создать виртуальную среду для разработки/сборки nodejs-приложений?

Tags: javascript, node.js, jetbrains, virtualenv

Изучаю NodeJS. Хочу cделать так, чтобы каждый проект имел свою env и при этом - не хранил зависимости system-wide.

Как это делается корректно (использование python-nodeenv, chroot, docker, или просто директория с node_modules+package.json)?

Будут ли с проектом при подобном использовании работать продукты JebBrains (отладка, инспектирование, автокомплит)?

Comment: Условно "node_modules + package.json", если не учитывать глобально установленную ноду.

Comment: Вот глобальную среду хочется избежать. Так чтобы я мог взять пример для старого Node (или LTS) и реализовать что-то своё на его примере, а потом открыть другой пример, где последняя версия Node и использовать то что написано там.

Comment: node_modules + package.js это зависимости проект. И ничто не помешает устанавливить саму ноду прямо в проект, хотя лично я склоняюсь к указанию версии в package.json + nvm, но это когда не пишу серверные приложения, для которых используется докер.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Самым простым способом оказалось устанавливать nodejs глобально и использовать package.json. 
А различный софт, который ставиться из npm вызываю вот так:

```
PATH=$(npm bin):$PATH $cli_util
```